# Field list pane in MS Access 2010 does not work as documented? (Add table field + create relation via drag&drop)

Tags: ms-access

The online documentation for MS Office 2010 implies the Field List Pane can be used during table design, but I am unable to reproduce the bahavior described in the online documentation.

What I was trying to do is, given 2 tables: Employee and EmployeeType, add a reference from Employee to EmployeeType via drag and drop.

The documentation indicates you can somehow drag the EmployeeType.TypeName column into the Employee table, and that will create the new column and define a new relationship between the two tables.

I am not seeing that behavior.

The documentation also states that you should be able to bring up the Field List Pane (Alt+F8) while in the datasheet view of another table, and [add a field from another table + create a relationship] via drag and drop.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-edit-or-delete-a-relationship-HA010341606.aspx#_Toc269467496

> Add a field and create a relationship from the Field List pane
>
> ```
> With the table open in Datasheet view, press ALT+F8. The Field List pane appears.
> Under Fields available in other tables, click the plus sign (+) next to a table name to display the list of fields in that table.
> Drag the field that you want from the Field List pane to the table that is open in Datasheet view.
> When the insertion line appears, drop the field into position.
> ```
>
> The Lookup Wizard starts.
>
> ```
> Follow the instructions to complete the Lookup Wizard.
> ```
>
> The field appears in the table in Datasheet view.
>
> When you drag a field from an "other" (unrelated) table and then
>   complete the Lookup Wizard, a new one-to-many relationship is
>   automatically created between the table in the Field List and the
>   table to which you dragged the field. This relationship, created by
>   Access, does not enforce referential integrity by default. To enforce
>   referential integrity, you must edit the relationship.

I am not seeing that behavior.  When I bring up the Field List Wondow, it shows: No fields available to be added to the current view.

**Should this actually work?  Do I possibly have a bad install?**

### Edit

Moderators, **please don't close this question**, as there are several instances on the internet of people having this exact problem, with no followup on the issue.  This seems to be a rare and unacknowledged bug in Access 2010 so there is value in having it documented here.

Comment: This belongs on SuperUser, I reckon. Are you looking at a table, or a datasheet form? Choose to create a form, selecting datasheet from More Forms, now try alt+F8. BTW most people who use MS Access a lot **never** use look-ups in tables and are pretty careful about creating relationships. Note that the documentation says that you will have to edit the relationship to enforce referential integrity, so you would be better off going the long way round in the first place and getting it right.

Comment: @Remou: 1.this is in datasheet view. 2."...never use look-ups in tables" - why would this be?

Comment: Lookups: http://access.mvps.org/access/lookupfields.htm

Comment: Wow, yes, those are good enough reasons.  It's so frustrating that MS has deliberately crippled Access so much.  Why can't we drag a field from one table to another to create relationships in the relationship designer, and without having to also acceptable the extra action of creating a combo box interface on the table itself, over and above the simple relationship.  Access could be so powerful and productive, but they've essentially done nothing with it for a decade.  Arggh.  Thanks man.

Comment: For the most part I avoid using any kind of Wizard in Access, unless you are absolutely certain that what it gives you is OK. Wizards tend to generate bad code. Or make use of junk features. And you're right. Access has got little more than GUI Candy over the last 10 years or so. I wish they would listen to developers but I guess they figure that real developers will use .NET.

Comment: I think it is moreso of a case that MS doesn't want to give Access too much power as it sucks resources (both finances and users) from their more lucrative and strategic development platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using the Field List Pane when in *Datasheet View* for a table should be possible, it should display a list of other tables/columns in the existing database, and you should be able to drag a column from another table and drop it into the desired position in the table in datasheet view, which will:

1. Create that new column
2. Define a new database relationship between the two tables (but you may have to manually edit that relationship afterwards, as all relationship options are *not* available to you during this process.
3. Create a combo box as the Lookup Display Control, using the source table/column as the RowSource (whether this is desirable is highly questionable as per the comments others have pointed out on the original question, or summarized here: http://access.mvps.org/access/lookupfields.htm)

I still do not know why it was unavailable to me, after screwing around trying different things, it suddenly starting working (and I couldn't reproduce it not working, trying the exact same things I was doing before).

Answer (score 2):

Just happened to me. 
Here's how I fixed it:
1. Be in datasheet view.
2. Create > Form
3. Click "Edit Table" in the Field List Pane. A new tab should open and everything should work.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. All of the documentation I read said to click "Add existing fields" --> "Show all tables" then simply drag and drop the desired field and the appropriate control type would appear, yet everytime I tried actually doing this, it would display the field as a datasheet.

I was doing this in LAYOUT VIEW, when I switched to DESIGN VIEW, then attempted to drag and drop, it actually worked the way it's supposed to. I think I've seen tutorials where they do it in layout view so there's probably still a bug somewhere, but this seems to be a workaround